# How to avoid broken pipe in commands with cat?

Tags: pipe, emacs, cat

Why does this simple command fails using emacs shell (eshell)?

```
cat file.txt | wc
```

I have a file with 10241 lines. Each line has less than 50 characters. Around 90% of the times I launch this command, it gives the wrong result, namely line count. Nonetheless, no error messages are given.

Looks like broken pipe is a very common topic, but I haven't found any reasonable explanation. Also, no one proposes any workarounds. How can I get this simple command working reliably?

Of course, I could've just run `wc file.txt`. But I'm looking for a more general solution in which any tool would work fine piped cat: `cat file.txt | any_tool_here`.

**Details**

I'm using CentOS 5. This issue appears when using **eshell (emacs shell)**. I'm using GNU Emacs 24.5.2.

**Experiments**

Samples of results using `cat file.txt | wc` (expected: first column to be always 10241).

1. 8568   25706  110571
2. 9837   29513  126947
3. 5395   16187   69615
4. 9202   27608  118757
5. 7299   21899   94199
6. 9837   29513  126947

Sample of results using `wc file.txt`:

1. 10241  30723 132156
2. 10241  30723 132156
3. 10241  30723 132156
4. 10241  30723 132156
5. 10241  30723 132156
6. 10241  30723 132156

The cat command itself (when executed alone) is working properly. I validated it with the following command (a few times): `cat file.txt > file2.txt`. Then, I diff'd both files and they are identical.

Comment: What you are describing is not normal. Any tool *does* work fine with piped `cat`, I've never seen what you describe (and I just tested it with a file with 10240 lines of 50 characters each; it ran 1000 times with no error). Are you running this while another process is writing to `file.txt`? What operating system are you using?

Comment: No other process has access to file.txt. I'm using CentOS 5.

Comment: OK. Please [edit] your question and i) mention the OS; ii) give us an example of the file you are using that reproduces the error; iii) give us the *exact* error message. Are you sure the problem is a broken pipe? It sounds like you have something strange in your file. Does running `wc file.txt` always work as expected?

Comment: In what way is the result wrong? This really looks like the file is being modified (so it's either not fully written yet when you cat it, or something is rewriting file repeatedly). If it's a local and well functioning disk and disk controller, there really isn't any other explanation for this, unless it's a bug. What's your shell, kernel build? And where does this cat come from? Is it aliased to something?

Comment: Check this: use /bin/cat instead of cat. And check the output of cat - does it look like the file should? Is the problem the pipe or cat?

Comment: @terdon Yes, running wc file.txt works as expected all the time.

Comment: @orion Using /bin/cat produces same error. Using only cat file, looks perfect.

Comment: Just a note "Broken pipe" usually refers to the error message / signal returned when a pipe is written to but its read end is closed, i.e. the second program of the pipeline has exited before the first is finished.

Comment: Sorry guys. I'm using eshell (emacs shell). This issue does not happen using the linux terminal.

Comment: Then it's emacs IO interacting weirdly with the commands. From eshell manual:

"Eshell is not a replacement for system shells such as bash or zsh. Use Eshell when you want to move text between Emacs and external processes; if you only want to pipe output from one external process to another (and then another, and so on), use a system shell, because Emacs’s IO system is buffer oriented, not stream oriented, and is very inefficient at such tasks. If you want to write shell scripts in Eshell, don’t; either write an elisp library or use a system shell. "

Comment: In essence... it looks like emacs buffering stalls the pipe, causing an empty read, which signals an end of stream.

Comment: @orion Do you want to write the answer, I accept it. Please, link the page where you found this?

Comment: Next time, please make sure to mention all these details in your question. it saves everyone a lot of time.

Comment: A weird shell or not, that's somewhat unexpected behaviour! Might be worth checking if the issue exists in current Emacs versions (CentOS 5 sounds a bit dated), and filing a bug if it does.

Comment: @terdon Sure, I'm sorry about that. I hadn't even realized I was using eshell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gathering from the information about the shell that was used (`eshell`), it appears that the streaming aspect of this shell is the culprit. Normally, piping means opening two ends of a pipe + fork/exec, so you get two processes that share a file descriptor to a pipe, and communication goes directly through the kernel. This way, nothing can get lost - it's guaranteed to be safe (although if it the pipe or any involved stream are buffered, you may have to wait for the first process to exit normally to flush out the last chunk of the stream).

Judging from the excerpt from [eshell manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/eshell.html):

> Eshell is not a replacement for system shells such as bash or zsh. Use
>   Eshell when you want to move text between Emacs and external
>   processes; if you only want to pipe output from one external process
>   to another (and then another, and so on), use a system shell, because
>   Emacs’s IO system is buffer oriented, not stream oriented, and is very
>   inefficient at such tasks. If you want to write shell scripts in
>   Eshell, don’t; either write an elisp library or use a system shell.

eshell is not doing it the normal way, but fakes the pipe using its "buffers" (emacs' representation of open files) as intermediate deposit for data, and (without further research) I'd guess that at some point, `wc` performs a `read`, and `emacs` responds with an empty chunk (and returning 0 from `read` is a signal that the stream has ended) instead of waiting for more input from the first program to fill the buffer. If that's the case, it means that eshell is not only inefficient but buggy when it comes to pipes.